# Incorrect use of Parent data widget - Flutter bottom-sheet

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

Here I have below Widget in my bttomsheet (showModalBottomSheet) :

```
 Flexible(
              child: ListView.separated(
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                        height: 20.h,
                      ),
                  itemCount: 22,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return NagarTiming("test");
                  }),
            ),
```

This works file while I run the application i.e. I can see list of widgets properly. But then I have generated the .apk file using command in android studio,

and then I have installed that apk in my android device,
The issue is : **bottomsheet opens but it has blank content, there is no list of widget and it giving below error** :

> > the following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
>
> The ParentDataWidget Flexible(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of
> type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept
> ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.
>
> Usually, this means that the Flexible widget has the wrong ancestor
> RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Flexible widgets are placed directly
> inside Flex widgets. The offending Flexible is currently placed inside
> a SizedBox widget.
>
> The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the
> incompatible parent data was:   _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#f71a8] ←
> NotificationListener ← Scrollable ←
> PrimaryScrollController ← ListView ← Flexible ← SizedBox ← Column ←
> Padding ← Container ← ⋯ When the exception was thrown, this was the
> stack:
> #0      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData. (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5960:11)

What might be the issue? Thanks.

Comment: remove Flexible Widget

Comment: Can you include full bottomSheet from  `showBottomSh...`

Comment: @NinadSawant by removing Flexible widget Listview is not showing its content in bottomsheet.

Comment: try giving ListView.separated  shrinkWrap : true property OR wrap your ListView.separated with sizedBox and give it finite height.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to know what `Flexible()` widget does and where it can be applied

1: If it is a direct child `Row()` widget

```
Row(
children[
 //your widget
 
         Flexible(
            child: ListView.separated(
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                      height: 20.h,
                    ),
                itemCount: 22,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return NagarTiming("test");
                }),
          ), 
 ]

 )
```

2: If it is a direct child `Column()` widget

```
Column(
children[
 //your widget
 
         Flexible(
            child: ListView.separated(
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                      height: 20.h,
                    ),
                itemCount: 22,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return NagarTiming("test");
                }),
          ), 
 ]

 )
```

If you still don't attain your desired appearance remove the `Flexible()` and wrap with `SizedBox()` or `Container()` with desired height of course or you could use `Wrap()` widget instead. Fo more see this [api](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html)

Comment: Yes It is a children widget of Column widget.

Comment: Not working with SizedBox, Container and Wrap

Comment: Please add more code so I can  at least know the that comes before the `Flexible()` widget